# How can I prevent ng-options from calculation until object is assigned a value?

Tags: angularjs

I have a code in my app:

```
ng-options="method.name for selectedHelp.methods in selectedHelp"
```

But the whole select tag is hidden, until "selectedHelp" variable is assigned a value. How can I also prevent ng-options from calculation until that "selectedHelp" has a value? Because otherwise it throws an error.

Comment: And you can't give is a default value on load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `ng-if` to hide the `ng-options` until selectedHelp is available:

```
<select ng-if="selectedHelp" ng-options>
</select>
```

Comment: Works great. Will mark as a solution in 5 minutes. (Stackoverflow requires to wait 10 minutes after question creation to mark any answer as solution).

Comment: Sorry to be pedantic but `ng-if` doesn't hide the element, it removes it entirely from the DOM and the re-inserts it. `ng-show/hide` will only hide or show the element.